# Azure websites - high latency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, latency

We are hosting several ASP.NET MVC sites on Azure (Wesites in standard mode) and recently we have run into an issue with high latency - the server takes very long time to respond even for static files.

The developer console in Chrome shows these data for a sample image file (100kB):

- connecting 12ms
- sending 3ms
- waiting 1856ms
- receiving 89ms

We have configured autoscaling, so the website can scale out if the server gets to busy, but it doesn't seem to help.

Any idea, where the problem could be?

**Edit:**

The site is hosted in the West Europe region.

It appears, that the problem isn't in our ASP.NET application. I have created a new  [website](http://test-dmp.azurewebsites.net/test.jpg) that contains only static files and response times are also bad.

Comment: I don't see anything on the service dashboard (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/). How recently have you been encountering the issue and for what duration?

Comment: Are you still experiencing the problem, I am not able to replicate it with my AzureWebsites. Can you share the URL with which you are encountering the problem? Is this issue happening in a timely manner, I mean daily at some times? Do you see any unusual activity on Website Monitoring Dashboard?

Comment: It started yesterday and since then, the performance is consistently bad. There isn't anything unusual on the monitoring dashboard. URL of the website is http://live-zsvhejny-dmp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: I do see a similar degradation of response times with our WAWS. Standard mode in region West Europe.

Comment: What is in the eventlog.xml file?

Comment: We could have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454292/azure-website-constantly-restarts-due-to-slow-requests-limit

Comment: from eventlog: For a WCF service "Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (43069440 bytes) is less than 5% of total memory.  As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests"  for other requests: Worker Process  requested recycle due to 'Slow Requests' limit.  Seems like the machines really run on the edge. Not amused.

Comment: Switching to instance size M has solved this for us ... for now.

Comment: Switching to Shared mode helped for us but switching the size didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to instance size M has solved this for us ... for now.

Comment: Scaling up to M and then scaling down back to S (probably moving the web site to another physical box) helped, but I am afraid, that the problem could appear again.

Comment: @LukasKabrt Right, it happened two times with us, the reason is still unknown :(

Comment: Yes, switching does change the machine the site is running on. They use a kind of "buffer of machines" [see twitter](https://twitter.com/nirmsk/status/342087643779198977)

Answer (score 0):

I copy-paste [the answer from my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21464708/974487) because I think we have the same problem

I got a reply from Windows Azure Web Sites Team [on MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/8f6fc304-75b0-4c2c-bd8d-5caa507c66da/azure-website-constantly-restarts-due-to-slow-requests-limit?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview&prof=required):

> We have identified this issue as a bug in new Auto-Heal feature we shipped recently. Please add following in your web.config file to mitigate this issue for now.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <monitoring>
            <triggers>
                <slowRequests timeTaken="02:00:00" count="1000000000" timeInterval="00:01:00" />
            </triggers>
            <actions value="LogEvent" />
        </monitoring>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> We are working on releasing the fix ASAP.
>
> Apologies for inconvenience.
>
> Windows Azure Web Sites Team

**Update:** The workaround works only in Standard mode. It throws an error in Shared or Free mode, so be aware.