# Azure website constantly restarts due to 'Slow Requests' limit

Tags: iis, azure, appdomain, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure website setup in West-Europe and in Standard mode. Suddenly today at 30 January 2014 03:00 am UTC it started constantly restart the app pool. The ShutdownReason is HostingEnvironment.
I have a lot of these events in eventlog.xml:

```
<Event>
    <System>
        <Provider Name="W3SVC-WP"/>
        <EventID>2299</EventID>
        <Level>3</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="9:14:50 AM"/>
        <EventRecordID>15807234</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer>RD00155D3A08C6</Computer>
        <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>Worker Process  requested recycle due to 'Slow Requests' limit.
        </Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

I can't find any info about the 'Slow Requests' limit.
These restarts aren't related to the code, nothing was changed for a week.
Only switching the web site mode to Shared helped me.

It's the second time it happened and I don't understand the reason of such behavior.

Comment: Consider asking this question on Azure MSDN Forum http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/home?category=windowsazureplatform%2Cazuremarketplace%2Cwindowsazureplatformctp

Comment: @JakubKonecki Thanks, I did :) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/8f6fc304-75b0-4c2c-bd8d-5caa507c66da/azure-website-constantly-restarts-due-to-slow-requests-limit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a reply from Windows Azure Web Sites Team [on MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/8f6fc304-75b0-4c2c-bd8d-5caa507c66da/azure-website-constantly-restarts-due-to-slow-requests-limit?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview&prof=required):

> We have identified this issue as a bug in new Auto-Heal feature we shipped recently. Please add following in your web.config file to mitigate this issue for now.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <monitoring>
            <triggers>
                <slowRequests timeTaken="02:00:00" count="1000000000" timeInterval="00:01:00" />
            </triggers>
            <actions value="LogEvent" />
        </monitoring>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> We are working on releasing the fix ASAP.
>
> Apologies for inconvenience.
>
> Windows Azure Web Sites Team

**Update:** The workaround works only in Standard mode. It throws an error in Shared or Free mode, so be aware.

Comment: I am probably having the same issue. It started restarting and I receive Http 503 errors. However, VS complains <monitoring> is not a valid child element of <system.webServer>. Do you have the same issue ?

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi Yes, I have the same issue, unfortunately.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi It works only in Standard mode :) I updated the answer.

Comment: So a question here how is everyone getting the monitoring section to work?  I can't even run the app locally in VS with it there.  Are you only adding it when you deploy it?

Comment: @runxc1BretFerrier Config transformations will help you. Just add monitoring section for production environment only.